# Unable to read html page using the urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I am using the 2.7.12 version of python (on Windows 7) and trying to use the urllib for the first time. below are the 3 simple statements but somehow when i execute it the program window/cmd prompt hangs :

```
import urllib
url = r'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print len(html)
```

Is there something wrong in the way the page is being called. This issue is not for this specific html page, i have tried for several others as well. Is there some settings that i need to change on my computer to be able to use this successfully. I have tried the readline() to get the content, it works until the last line after which it tries to retrieve data from the html page and the program/cmd prompt hangs.

Comment: The code seems correct ... dont click in the cmd-window that blocks the execution.

Comment: That script works perfectly well for me. Is it possible that you have an HTTP proxy? Perhaps the proxy is (incorrectly) causing this problem.

Comment: @Robᵩ - thanks for the hint. It really was the proxy PAC in the browser setting. Just disabled it and now all is good.